# How does one notate label equations for future reference?

Tags: label

Within a LaTeX paper, I would like to mark each equation with a specific label so that I can reference them again within the same paper, similar to how pictures or charts are labeled "Figure #". In most papers, I haven't seen equations with their own labels, only in steps of their manipulation. I haven't seen a singular convention across different papers, so I am wondering if there is a most common one.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely label the equation. You have to Enclose your equation in "\begin-end{equation}" and associate any label. See code below:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}
```

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking though, it's not meant to be any kind of tech support. The question is asking in general what the convention is for labeling any equations for reference within the same paper math papers across the world. Latex is just detail.